# Wildcard asterisk character ("*") in SQL database

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

Can we use the asterisk character `*` for a search action in SQL database?

```
MASQLComm = New SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) AS [RecCount] 
                              From " & tName & " 
                             WHERE " & tName & fName & " = '" & {*} & ".Temp' ", 
                            SQLConn)
```

Please advice me with a code for this.

Comment: It sounds like you want `LIKE`.

Comment: This code seem very vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`LIKE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) operator to do that.

Also I would strongly recommend against building your SQL query like that. Do it if there is no other way.

Comment: Finally I have to look at the syntax of the operator LIKE, because we can use it as:  myString = "GodDay.Temp" myFinalString = mystring Like "*.Temp" and we will have the "GoodDay". And that only when we use it inside the code not for SQL query.

Comment: Using LIKE operator with % works in SQL. For example, `SomeColumn LIKE '%.Temp'` will return all rows where data in `SomeColumn` column ends with .Temp.

Answer (score 9):

For text you need LIKE with '%'.  But make sure you're acquainted with Bobby Tables.
http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: +1 but... Just in case the joke is lost, google "SQL Injection"